# viewWillAppear/Disappear being called twice on modal presentation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I have a TabBarController with 4 tabs. Each tab has an embedded UINavigationController and their own respective root views. If I am on any of the tabs and select an on screen button to display a new VC via modal presentation the viewWillDisappear method from the original tab view will be called twice. If I then dismiss the modal view to return to the root tab view the viewWillAppear method will also be called twice. This only occurs when using modal presentations. If I just push a new VC onto the UINavigationController there are no problems at all.

The method, which is calling the modal presentation:

```
- (void)presentNewVC
{

    NewVC *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StringEditVC"];

    NewNavigationVC *navVC = [[NavigationVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:newVC];

    [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The VC that this is being called from happens to be a UITableViewController. For clarification I'll show an example of how things are laid out.

UITabBarController -> 4 tabs

Each Tab:

UINavigationController -> UITableViewController

The UITableViewController has a button on each cell that when pressed executes the method above to present a new VC modally. When I select that action the modal view is presented correctly, but the UITableViewController's viewWillDisappear is fired twice. When I dismiss the modal view to return, the UITableViewController's viewWillAppear is also fired twice. If I happened to just select the cell itself from the UITableViewController it will work correctly and push the new view onto the UINavigationController without calling anything twice.

edit:

I just checked the top level tab bar controller and its viewWillAppear/Disappear method is being called twice when I initially open the app.

Comment: You should take a look at the stack trace when `viewWillAppear` are called.

Comment: How did you create the tabBarController? Can you show the code? I just tried to replicate your issue but it works fine on my end, only calling viewWillAppear once when you'd expect it to. If there was a way to share the project I'm pretty sure I could figure it out pretty quick for you.

Comment: @Mike The tabBarController is implemented via storyboards. I put some NSLog statements to check the appearing/disappearing of the VC's. When the app starts it has a single VC and then you login, which presents the main tabBarController via modal. That initial tabBarController's viewWillAppear is called twice. If I leave that tabBarVC by going to different page and then come back, it is only called once. I have only seen issues with this when presenting screens modally.

Comment: I tried to replicate this issue by creating a new project with a regular view controller as the root view controller, adding a button in the navbar that when pressed presents a tabbar controller, and in the tabbar controller's view will appear I put a log statement there, and it only printed once. I admit I never do anything via storyboards so my guess is your issue lies somewhere therein, but I don't think I can help you if that's the case.

Comment: @Mike I appreciate you looking into it! I might have to change things up and do it programmatically to see if that can fix it! I'll let you know the results. Thanks again!